# Why define a function prototype, then preprocessor macro with the same name?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I'm reading a book about C, and somewhere in the authors code I found a definition of a function prototype, then a macro with the same name, and there is no definition of the function itself neither in any `.h` or `.c` file.

I mean something like that:

```
int print_my_stufff(char *stuff);
#define print_my_stuff(A) (printf("%s\n", A))
/* and print-my-stuff() function never defined anywhere else */
```

The code works, but i just don't get why he needed a function prototype in the first place? Couldn't he just write a macro? What's the point? Is it to tell a compiler that a macro should be evaluated to an expression which returns `int` or what? Removing the prototype doesn't seems to change a behavior. The author didn't explain this.

Comment: Maybe it is to document the macro. Particularly the return type and parameter types. The author may be doing that just for the book or the author may even think that is a good practice in general.

Comment: I've never seen put into use in practice, so I can only guess: maybe the prototype is for documenting the macro's parameter types?

Comment: @kaylum Then why not just write a comment? `//this macro does foo`

Comment: @Arc676 Why do some people like apples and others like oranges?

Comment: @Arc676 that's behaviour. Functions are strongly typed, so it's probably more debug friendly

Comment: the `print_my_stuff` does not match the `printf_my_stufff`   is this just shakey typing or an actual error?

Comment: the reality is that macros are incorporated at pre-processor time.  They are a direct text replacement of the body of the macro, not the name of the macro.  So when that macro is invoked by some code that has something like: `char myArray[] = {"hello"};  print_my_stuff(myArray);`   what is actually in the code is: `char myArray[] = {"hello"};  printf("%s\n", myArray);`  And the parens around the body of the macro are so there are no 'text replacement' errors.  The prototype is a complete waste of space as it means/changes nothing

Comment: @n.m it's learn C the hard way (you can see authors code i'm talking about here if you want: http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex44.html ).

Comment: Why not write the author and ask?

Comment: @n.m. good idea, email sent. Maybe the author will even come here and answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an outdated practice, from before `inline` functions. If you call the function as in `print_my_stuff("hello")`, then the preprocessor will see the call syntax and insert the contents of the macro. If you use the name otherwise, as in `f_ptr = &print_my_stuff`, the compiler will use the actual function.

Calling the function as `(print_my_stuff)("hello")` will also bypass the macro. Some paranoid style guides even require parenthesizing certain function names because Macros Are Evil.

Comment: In the first case, what address will it use? The function doesn't have a body

Comment: @AndréFratelli Which case is the first case? It never sees any function if the macro is used.

Comment: Here `If you use the name otherwise, as in f_ptr = &print_my_stuff, the compiler will use the actual function.` The address is being taken, but what address?

Comment: @AndréFratelli If the function is used but never defined, you'll get a link error. If the book describes writing a prototype with no definition, then its problems are deeper than anachronism.

Comment: I guess you're right. I didn't know about this resolution, it's nice to know

Comment: @AndréFratelli Same address that would be used if the macro wasn't there.